# Sound Issues: No Sound in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, soundcard

I'm currently having issues getting my sound to work.  I've read others have had luck with upgrading their kernel and I've done that:

```
noahc@blackbox:~$ uname -r
3.7.0-030700-generic
```

I get this for output:

```
noahc@blackbox:~$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've read that others have had luck with plugging in a set of headphones, which I have tried and had no such luck.

Any ideas on how to move forward with this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it fixed by following this:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iTlJ8BfqXUjaHO__TEdlkvuqB1WLOkGaudngc5SFLMI/edit?pli=1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Seth Everyone probably says they are the exception to the rule, but the documentation is literally 20 pages long and I followed it from beginning to end. It's been a while, but there are multiple restarts involved and redoing things over and over again getting further along in the process. Not sure I can really say what the essential parts are, as it's a process to fix it not a process to determine what all is broken.